# Why does slider block the menu?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a website for a new charity: http://www.ukraineaid.org/

The Meta Slider plugin has been inserted using PHP into the front page of this Wordpress site. It blocks the menu above. I can't click any links in the menu. Other pages are fine.

Can anyone suggest what to do with the CSS? Anyone willing to help me fix this site for the charity? They need to go live soon and I am doing this for them out of kindness. Anyone else want to help, please let me know.

Comment: Also I need to center the slider. I also want to change the dots to a menu that shows a darker color on mouseover, eg when the War Relief image is displayed the war relief button of the horizontal menu below the slider turns from blue to red then the orphans button turns from blue to red and so on... instead of the little dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add/edit in style.css line 42

```
.header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 1; /* z-index to take it on top */
position: relative; /* z-index to work */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now how many I center the slider and replace the dots with a horizontal menu that mouseover/slider change changes the bg color of menu?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: The big pictures (slider) is not centered, it is located to the left, i want it in the center.